# $_POST merging array and storing in only one column

Tags: php, ajax, database

I have a form that posts to a php handler which saves the data from the form into a database. 
I don't think the save function is the problem. I think its a problem with the `$_POST` merging the forms data. When I view the sql table, the data is there but all the values are appearing in one column so the variables are being passed from the form correctly.

This is my code:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$com_dis = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

$lowercase = strtolower($email);
$image = md5( $lowercase );

try{
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments ( com_name, com_email, com_dis, post_id_fk ) VALUES ( :name, :email, :com_dis, :id )';
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":com_dis", $com_dis, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
}catch(PDOException $e ){
    echo "QUERY FAILED" . $e->getMessage();
};
```

If I use `$id = $_POST['id']` for all the variables, it gets an unidentified index error thrown. When I print `$_POST` it displays an array where the array is called name and the contents are just the rest of the variables which is the same data stored in the table.

How do I either get the data to save correctly or stop `$_POST` from merging the variable so they? save in the correct columns?

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/><br />
    <span class="titles">Name</span><span class="star">*</span><br /><input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br />

    <span class="titles">Email</span><span class="star">*</span><br /><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br />

    Comment<br /><textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value=" Submit Comment " />
</form>
```

The form is passed via AJAX:

```
$(function() {

    $(".submit").click(function() {

        name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + 'email=' + email + 'comment=' + comment + 'id=' + id;

        if(name=='' || email=='' || comment==''){
            alert('Please Give Valid Details');
        }

        else{
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "commentajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){

                    $("ol#update").append(html);
                    $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                    document.getElementById('email').value='';
                    document.getElementById('name').value='';
                    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
                    $("#name").focus();

                    $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: how about showing what `var_dump($_POST)` shows, if you think that's the problem? We can't guess what you form looks like, or how the data's coming across.

Comment: What do you mean it is only saved in one column - only one column is saved or all the values are appearing in one column instead of their own, respectively? If only one column is saved, which is it?

Comment: when i dump the variable this is the result 'array(1) { ["name"]=> string(28) "asdemail=asdcomment=asdid=38" }'

Comment: all the values are appearing in one column

Comment: i have added the form @AlienWebguy

Comment: and when you set action to be $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Comment: Is that form copied/pasted or re-typed? Show me the form in the HTML source code, not your PHP file please.

Comment: the output is exactly the same as before

Comment: how about your ajax?can you paste it

Comment: It shouldn't be. You shouldn't see `<?php echo $id; ?>` - I imagine you'd see like `12`

Comment: that is the form exactly copied from html source @AlienWebguy

Comment: Is this on a public staging environment you can link to?

Comment: your php shouldn't be exposed in source code

Comment: no its on a protected web server which can only be remotely linked to

Comment: Got it, see my answer. Cheers~

Comment: it is indented just adding spaces for code block messes it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate your data string:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + 'email=' + email + 'comment=' + comment + 'id=' + id;
```

should be

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment + '&id=' + id;
```

Comment: oh for god sake I've just wasted 4 hours of my life trying to find the problem turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. Thank you so much.